# Python Dash DataTable: row selection not working

Tags: python, datatable, plotly-dash

When I set row_selectable as 'multi' in a DataTable, I would expect an extra column on the very left with checkboxes to select arbitrary rows. However, when I do it, that column does not contain any checkboxes. Therefore, row selection is not possible.

```
import dash
import dash_table
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/solar.csv')

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    id='table',
    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
    data=df.to_dict("rows"),
    row_selectable='multi'
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

row_selectable='single' results in the same output. I am using Python 3.6.8, dash 0.39.0, dash-table 3.6.0

Can somebody help, please?

Comment: I ran your example with a dummy dataframe, `df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(30).reshape(5, 6))`, and the checkboxes appeared on the left correctly. I'm using the same version of everything except I have Python 3.7, but I doubt that would make a difference. I set up a simple callback as well, showing the selections, and it handles multiple selections fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A css file had made the checkboxes disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Please install the latest dash

pip install dash==1.12.0

This will fix the issue.